# SpEL with @Query in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

im running a query on ES but the number of params are increasing (due to business reasons).

According to the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query) in spring data elastic search you can use `@Query` with ordered parameters like `?0`, `?1` and so on for parameters given in the signature of the method but this approach seems a bit uncomfortable

Is it possible to make a query like `:#{#myParam.myPropOfMyParam}` in other words use SpEL to access argument properties?

and not end with a method with a bunch of parameters like

```java
@Query("match.... ?0,.. ?1, ?2")
Page<Doc> findBy(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, Pageable pageable)
```

and to be more like spring-data-jpa uses

```java
public interface CompanyDocRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<CompanyDoc, UUID> {

    @Query(value =
            "{\n" +
                    "  \"multi_match\": {\n" +
                    "    \"query\": \"#{#keyword['somevalue']}\",\n" +
                    "    \"fields\": [\n" +
                    "      \"name\",\n" +
                    "      \"description\",\n" +
                    "      \"city\",\n" +
                    "      \"department\",\n" +
                    "      \"sectors.sector.descriptionSector\",\n" +
                    "      \"sectors.sector.description\",\n" +
                    "      \"sectors.sector.name\",\n" +
                    "      \"interests.name\"\n" +
                    "    ]\n" +
                    "  }\n" +
                    "}\n")
    Page<CompanyDoc> findByKeyword(@Param("keyword") Map<String,String> keyword, Pageable pageable);

   
}
```

or if there are other ways to make a query without leave a side spring data interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. You might want to create an issue for this at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues

Comment: thx, for the answer, already submited meanwhie i think ill use criteria to build these querys, [#2083](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2083)