# Using @Query to access a data object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a Spring Elastic Repository function that has way too many parameters (11 parameters).

I want to be able to access members of class objects to reduce the parameter count.  Is there a way to access class members via `@Query`?  For example, I want to access members of the following class:

```java
public class Header {
    int version;
    string timestamp;
}
```

and want to do a query as follows:

```java
@Query("""
    {
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                { "match": { "header_version": {"query": "<header version substitution>"}}},
                { "match": { "header_timestamp": {"query": "<header timestamp substitution>"}}},
                { "match": { "body": {"query": "<body value>"}}}
            ]
        }
    }
""")
List<Result> findEntry(Header header, String body);
```

Where:

```java
public class Result {
    int version;
    String timestamp;
    String body;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71070617/spel-with-query-in-spring-data-elasticsearch

Comment: Damn... It can't handle nested objects.  At least there's now a feature request for this function